# Failing an audit on a one-line answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

I was reviewing the first posts and then I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18171411). It's an answer to a question and the answer only contains one line which I flagged to be a comment since it's not an answer.

This is the answer in the post:

> Starting today /media no longer works. But https://www.instagram.com/nfl/?__a=1 still works"

I flagged it as *not an answer*, which lead to me failing and closer to being banned from review.

I don't understand; this obviously should be a comment, but it got so many upvotes and thus I failed.

Also as a suggestion, can the ban in review just be on the specific section in the review and not everything?

Comment: Both answers aren't that good and the accepted one even says that the question is a dupe.

Comment: Please explain why you think it's not an answer.

Comment: It does look like an answer (a short one) to me..Maybe there could be a better one.. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120850/4826457) is definitely not..And both are included in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/4826457)

Comment: _"It's an answer to a question"_ - _"I flagged it as not an answer"_ - You see the problem? ;)

Comment: According to the [timline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47184975/timeline), three other users also failed that audit.

Comment: I flagged both that answer and the accepted one which also was a link only answer as not an answer (very low quality would have been better but that flag wasn't available for some reason), so it probably won't show up as an audit again.

Comment: @DonaldDuck That an answer contains a link doesn't make it a link only answer, nor does it make it VLQ.  Removing an audit that was helping to stop people from incorrectly trying to delete content that doesn't merit deletion isn't exactly a good accomplishment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long and short of it is that this answer is really borderline, but the system doesn't know that.

This is the kind of pseudo-answer breadcrumb that you stumble upon while searching for the solution to an intractable problem, that gives you just enough information, not to resolve the problem, but to refine your search and maybe find the real answer.

Some people find that sort of thing valuable enough to spend an upvote on. I usually don't, personally, unless there's a *really* incisive, eye-opening point contained within.*

Regardless, the accumulated upvotes from happy hunters made the system select this as a "good post" audit candidate. You correctly identified it as borderline, decided it was on the wrong side of the line, and got dinged. Basically all you need to know, going forward, is that some people are going to disagree with you about which side of the line not-quite-terrible posts fall on.

Hand-selected audits would probably be a good solution for this; a "this audit sucked and it should feel bad for failing me" button might work too, but most people would probably just click it reflexively.

---

*Ideally we'd remove this in favor of a more complete explanation. Lacking that ideal alternative answer, there's an argument to be made for at least keeping this one hanging around.

Comment: You're free to argue that the *quality* of the answer is borderline (or even below the border of good quality, if you'd like). But it's *not* borderline in being an answer.  The post is *unambiguously* trying to answer the question.  That you don't think it's a good or high quality answer doesn't make it Not An Answer.  It's a perfectly fine post as an audit.  If someone is saying that that post isn't an answer, then they're not reviewing correctly, and are *correctly* getting a failed audit mark on their record.